# Xpages - New version of CkEditor not load

Tags: ckeditor, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Recently I decide to migrate my application from version 8.5.3 Lotus Notes to version 9.0.1. When doing this I needed to change the version of CkEditor from 4.4.7 to 4.5.3, so I changed the file in the \data \ domino\html\ckeditor folder, however when re-building my application I received the following error in browser console:

[The file xsp/.ibmxspres/domino/ckeditor/plugins/ibmspellchecker/plugin.js  not exists in the new version of ckEditor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgecx.png)

I realized this is because the application tries to fetch the javascripts files from the old version of CkEditor, as if it were cached.
I've tried everything specified here: http://www.intec.co.uk/dde-local-preview-ckeditor/ but nothing worked.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I haven't upgraded ckeditor myself but Sven Hasselbach has a blog post about serving a different version of ckeditor from within an NSF so maybe that will be relevant for you
http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1407

Comment: Does the same happen when developing against a Domino server as well? The instructions I gave are specific to DDE only, because OSGi plugins are served differently for DDE local preview. Now that Domino server has a non-production license, I would overwhelmingly recommend that approach for development. For the server, confirm CKEditor is loading from domino/html folder - that may exist only to support apps compiled to run as 8.5.3. It looks like default CKEditor may get loaded from an OSGi plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand: you are upgrading CKEditor by yourself instead of using the default version that is installed and doing this by installing a version of CKEditor that you have obtained from CKEditor directly.

If so, the problem may be that the xpages inputRichText control uses some CKEditor plugins that are provided by IBM e.g. ibmspellchecker, ibmxspimage and these won't be provided in the standard CKEditor distribution.

If these plugins are not present in your new CKEditor installation then the editor will not load properly.

You have 2 options

1. Ensure these IBM plugins are put back in the html/ckeditor/plugins directory (and hope they are still compatible with the CKEditor version)
2. Tell the inputRichText control *not* to load any of the ibm plugins. (but this means you will not be able to upload images)

To remove plugins from the editor config use the dojoAttribute 'removePlugins'

```
<xp:inputRichText id="inputRichText1">
    <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
        <xp:dojoAttribute name="removePlugins" value="ibmspellchecker,etc"></xp:dojoAttribute>
    </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
</xp:inputRichText>
```